# Manage IIS without being local administrator in iis 5.1

Tags: iis

How to Manage IIS without being local administrator in iis 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a machine admin in order to fully administer IIS (locally or remotely) using the IIS Manager GUI. I think you can do some basic tasks as an operator but they are severely limited.

Alternatively you can use the Metabase Explorer and give permissions through that (it works just like the registy editor). Admin access is not needed but it is a huge pain to perform admin tasks that way, is not supported by MS, and you can completely destroy your installation if you aren't extremely careful.
http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.inetserver.iis.security/2004-03/0132.html

Comment: HI ktharsis, thank you for your help, but the above article, that is for IIS 6.0, i need the same for IIS 5.1...

Comment: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1276 (works on 5, 5.1, and 6)

Comment: Can any one advice me whether this method of giving access to IIS is advisable ?

Comment: Not at all. The only time you should use the metabase is if you are already an adept IIS admin and just need to change/verify a single (or very few settings). Not supported by MS at all (as stated in my answer and in the linked explanation).